# Pyqt5 designer and Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to coding. I'm really enjoying it and have worked my way through a number of tutorials for Python 3 and feel the basics are coming along. I've now started to think about gui creation. I first started with tkinter but quickly decided that pyqt5 was good for me. I've started a tutorial that I found from zetcode that is really helping me out.

I've now come across something called the pyqt designer which looks like a significant string to my bow.... The only problem is, is that I can't find it on my system. I can find pyqt designer.dll but nothing that I know how to boot. I am running Windows 10, pyqt5 and the newest install of Python 3.5.

Comment: How did you install pyqt? In windows the designer should be included by default.

Comment: From riverbank computing. If that's the case maybe I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling. So I guess nobody knows if any comparability issues?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem.

I fix it be installing additional tools with

> pip install PyQt5-tools

Then I located the "designer.exe" executable in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer`

[Tools to supplement the official PyQt5 wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools)

Comment: On `WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5` the path was `WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

If you used one of the Windows [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), it should create a PyQt submenu which has a menu item for Qt Designer (amongst other things). Alternatively, you can start it by entering `designer` in the Run dialog or a Command Prompt window.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have found the correct install.exe file in the site and used the run command as you suggest. All is now good. Thanks again